# Windows Automated Install vs Imaging

Tags: clone, mdt, disk-imaging

Is it better to create a reference image and clone that image on all of the machines or is it better to use the the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit to do an automated install on every machine?  In a Lab setting with 25 identical machines why is one method better than the other?  What are the pros and cons of each method? Is speed the only factor?

Comment: Not a programming question. See the [help/on-topic] for guidelines here.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft says time is the only factor.  Takes about 20 mins to image and 3 hours or so to do a fresh automated install.  In my experience most of the time it takes to do an automated install eaten up by windows updates.